# How to run the word count job on hadoop yarn from Java code?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have a requirement like below:

1. there is a 30 node hadoop YARN cluster, and a client machine for job submission.
2. Let's use the wordcount MR example, since it's world famous. I'd like to submit and run the wordcount MR job from a java method.

So what's the code required to submit the job? anything specific to configurations on the client machine?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop should be present on your client machine, with the same configurations as other machines in your hadoop cluster.

To submit the MR job from a java method, please refer to java [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and pass the hadoop command to launch you wordcount example.

The command and necessary application specific requirements for wordcount can be found [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v2.0)

Answer (score 0):

You should make a class that implements Tool. An example here:

```
public class AggregateJob extends Configured implements Tool {

  @Override
  public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Job job = new Job(getConf());
    job.setJarByClass(getClass());
    job.setJobName(getClass().getSimpleName());

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setMapperClass(ProjectionMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(LongSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(LongSumReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int rc = ToolRunner.run(new AggregateJob(), args);
    System.exit(rc);
  }
}
```

This example was obtained from [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/hadoop-writing-and-running-your-first-pr/240153197?pgno=2). As @hamsa-zafar already say, the client machine should have present hadoop configuration, as any other node in the cluster.